# Constraint Layout and scrollview doesn't work

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-scrollview, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to realize a layout for my Android application. In the designer I can see everything is fine, but when I emulate (or when I install the application on my phone) the appearance is totally different. I attach how it appears in the designer. I see everything (as I would like), with a TextView, a ScrollView and a button, used to close the Diaolog.

**Blue print view of image**

[image: Blue print view of image]

When I emulate, the situation is totally different: there's no way playing with "match_parent", "wrap_content" and so on, to obtain a good result. I see a totally different result as follow.

**Emulated on device**

[image: Emulated on device]

I apply this layout to a Dialog, but I don't understand why I cannot obtain a simple layout with textview, scrollview of cardwiev and a button.

Here the snippet of code used to show the dialog:

```
public void Display_Data_CardView(int mode){
    Data_CardView_Dialog = new Dialog(this);
    Data_CardView_Dialog.getWindow();
    Data_CardView_Dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    Data_CardView_Dialog.setCancelable(false);
    try{
        if (mode == NO_IN_ANIM){
            Data_CardView_Dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogTheme2_no_in_anim;
        }else Data_CardView_Dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogTheme2;
    }catch (Exception e){

    }
    Data_CardView_Dialog.setContentView(R.layout.data_view_cards);


    Button btnOK = (Button) Data_CardView_Dialog.findViewById(R.id.btnCardViewOK);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Data_CardView_Dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    Data_CardView_Dialog.show();
}
```

And here my xml layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clDataViewCards"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitoloDataCardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Dati Letti"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glHoriz1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glHoriz1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svDataViewCards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glHoriz2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glHoriz1">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/item_wrapper_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard1"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView11"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 1" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView12"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 2" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_2"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard2"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView21"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 3" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView22"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 4" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard3"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView31"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 5" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView32"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 6" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_4"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard4"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView41"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 7" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView42"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 8" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard5"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView51"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 9" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView52"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 10" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard6"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView61"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 11" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView62"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 12" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_7"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard7"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView71"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 13" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView72"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 14" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/item_cardview_8"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
                app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ivCard8"
                        android:layout_width="36dp"
                        android:layout_height="36dp"
                        android:layout_margin="8dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                        tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="4dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView81"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 15" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView82"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:text="TextView 16/>

                    </LinearLayout>
                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glHoriz2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCardViewOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/Dialogo_View_Data_Cards_Bottone_OK"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glHoriz2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Can anyone help me to understand where I'm wrong?
Thankyou very much.

**EDIT**
I found a solution:I clode the scrollview into a LinearLayout, then I specified for that LinearLayout a width "match constraint". In the java, when I create the dialog, I change the width of the dialog changing the width of the first TextView, then I change the height of the scrollview, and I obtain what I'd like to do. I don't know if it is the way to do the thinks, but after a lot of tries, this is good for me.

Comment: use `0dp` for scrollview `layout_width`

Comment: @Sniffer thanks for you reply. I've tried to use 0dp and now I can see the layout as I expeted in term of TextBox+srollview+button. The only problem that remain is that now the cardviews inside the scrollview are not as in Designer but the text is scratched in a little space. I've to try to manage textview inside cardview I think

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Scrollview, please try to use NestedScrollview.

Comment: I obtain the same behavior. Nothing change using NestedScrollView. I can't understand. I thought it was simple: The extern container (ConstraintLayout) have to match the parent, inner view have to share the space in vertical. But it doesn't work in any of my attempts!

Answer (score 0):

this is ok for me :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/clDataViewCards"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTitoloDataCardView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Dati Letti"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|italic"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glHoriz1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glHoriz1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.1" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/svDataViewCards"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/glHoriz2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glHoriz1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/item_wrapper_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="8dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard1"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView11"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 1" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView12"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 2" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard2"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView21"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 3" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView22"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 4" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard3"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView31"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 5" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView32"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 6" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard4"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView41"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 7" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView42"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 8" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard5"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView51"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 9" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView52"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 10" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard6"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView61"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 11" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView62"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 12" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/item_cardview_7"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivCard7"
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_margin="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView71"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 13" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView72"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                    android:text="TextView 14" />

            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/item_cardview_8"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/ivCard8"
                    android:layout_width="36dp"
                    android:layout_height="36dp"
                    android:layout_margin="8dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/info_icon"
                    tools:ignore="contentDescription" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView73"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
                        android:text="TextView 13" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/textView74"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="TextView 14" />

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/glHoriz2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnCardViewOK"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:text="@string/state"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/glHoriz2" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

but i think count of item it not enough for scrolable

Comment: Your solution works but is not exactly what I'd like to obtain. I'm going crazy, maybe because I don't understand how Android thinks when has to calculate layout! I only desidere establish a dimension of the Dialog I'm going to create, so I can decide the amount of area to reserve to Scrollview, and I want to do it using the dimensions of the screen that I've calculate before. I want to do it programmatically. I create the layout and then I try to change width and height of the views, but I obtain strange results!

Comment: Wow.. this is not a easy job on android , man .. but it is good idea . I decided create a library for this in future . Good luck